# One Line if in Python Code Style

Tags: python, pep8

Looking for something like this:

```
if exits: sys.exit(msg)
if not result: print(msg)
if result: return msg
```

How to Apply Python Code Style?

Comment: You can use pretty much any popular IDE for this. They usually come with plugins that warn you if you're doing something that doesn't follow the guidelines specified in PEP8.

Comment: Yep,  I received a warning, But I do not want to write a multi-line,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one line if like this:

```
import sys
sys.exit(msg) if exits else (msg if result else  sys.stdout.write(msg))
```

Comment: `sys.stdout(message)` is not legal (you forgot `.write`, and unlike `print`, this doesn't add a new line for you). And this is just an abomination as far as code style goes; a three way output chained ternary, only one of which even returns anything meaningful? Ugh.

Comment: `print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)` 
old: `if condition:  if condition: `   i think this code is very ugly

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add indentation:

```
if exits: 
    sys.exit(msg)
if not result: 
    print(msg)
if result: 
    return msg
```

Unlike most other languages, Python is sensitive to indentations.